# Which formula should I use?

Tags: statistics

When doing two sample z test, I always fail to recognize which formula to use to calculate the standard error.

When do I use this formula?

[image]

And when do I pool the combination of success instead to calculate it?

[image]

Thanks for any helps!

Comment: The texts from which you learned these formulae should have specified relevant statistical assumptions.

Comment: @J.G., not really :( I am looking at a formula sheet and the only thing it tells is that we pool combination of success when we assuming p1 = p2 I am guess that means when we use the null Hypothesis assuming they are the same, we use the image 2 formula. I don't really know if this is correct so that's why I am asking here:/